# I am working on appending row in javascript but I actually don't know how to append an image in row cell

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, row

```
 [I am appending a row. everything appended but image not showing. I tried some ways but cant solve this problem][1]
function SearchDrivers() {
        var Id = document.getElementById('driverSearch').value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Administration/SearchDrivers/" + Id,
            type: "Get",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var table = document.getElementById('DriverTable');
                var drivers = response['users'];
                for (var j = 0; j <= drivers.length; j++) {
                    var driver = drivers[j];
                    tr = "<tr>"
                        + "<td>" + driver['email'] + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + driver['email'] + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + "033138445156666" + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + "<button class='table-btn'>unverified</button>" + "</td>"
```

this is the way i am appending  an image and its style. I used some more ways to append a image but thay also not working for me.

```
                        + "<td>" + "<a asp-action='DriverProfile'><img class='ml-2 icon-15' src='~/svg/visibility.svg'></a>" + "</td>"
                        + "</tr>";
                    $('#DriverTable tbody').append(tr);
                }



            }
            
        });
    }
```

Comment: It would be much better if you placed your code inside your question instead of link to it on an external website.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `svg` folder should be placed under `wwwroot.`

Then you need to change your path to

```
<img class='ml-2 icon-15' src='/svg/visibility.svg'></a>
```

Delete the `~`.

Comment: Thank You Its worked but Asp-action not working

Comment: The `asp-action` in `javascripts`cannot be recognized, you need to change it to `"<a href=" + "your herf" + ">" + "<img class='ml-2 icon-15' src='/svg/visibility.svg'>></a>"`